# ElasticSearch painless determine that field was array in source document

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Elasticsearch contains document like

```
{
  "array":["1","2"],
  "str": "123"
}
```

With mapping

```
"array" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to" : [
            "all"
          ],
          "norms" : false,
          "analyzer" : "logspeak"
        }
```

and

```
"str" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          },
          "copy_to" : [
            "all"
          ],
          "norms" : false,
          "analyzer" : "logspeak"
        }
```

If i do

```
Debug.explain(doc['array.keyword']);
```

and

```
Debug.explain(doc['str.keyword']);
```

I get `org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Strings` type for both fields.

How can i determine source field type? (I need get string length if field is simple string or size of array if field is array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct painless expression to use is:

```
def size = -1;
if (doc['array.keyword'].size() > 0) {
    // string case
    if (doc['array.keyword'].size() == 1) {
        size = doc['array.keyword'].value.length();
    } 
    // array case
    else {
        size = doc['array.keyword'].values.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do i correct understood that i can`t determine array of 1 element ?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [official ES documentation of arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) there is no array datatype in elasticsearch and as you are using the array of string, ES explain API returns the `String`. if you want to know the size of your array please see the @Val answer.

Comment: Actually, `doc['keyword-field'].values` is "equivalent" (i.e. the size will be the same) to the array in the source document